# Alphabetical Custom Menu

Tags: customization, menus

I'd like to create an alphabetical `a to z to #` custom menu on top of the regular menu. My website is about artists and lyrics. I'd like to have something similar to [this](https://www.azlyrics.com/) menu structure.

when you click on letter A: `azlyrics.com/a`

after that when you click on let's say ACDC: `azlyrics.crom/a/acdc`

and when you select the song it should show: `azlyrics.com/lyrics/acdc/you-shook-me-all-night-long`

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try wp plugin A-Z Listing: https://wordpress.org/plugins/a-z-listing/